# Win32 application doesn't run on startup

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have created a C++ Win32 application in Visual Studio 2015. My goal is to make it run at startup. I added a new entry in registry (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run). For an unknown reason, it doesn't work.

However it appears correctly in the Task Manager at the Startup tab but not in the Process tab which means it doesn't run at all. I tried to wrap it in a bat file. The bat runs but the application seems to fail at launch (or totally ignored, I can't tell exactly). If I launch manually from Program Files directory, it runs normally.

It's an old Visual project from a friend and it was converted in the current Visual (2015). If I create a new project from scratch, it works. But there is no reason for such behavior.

**Final thought** - I successully resolved my issue. My program was unable to find the SQLite file because any programs launch by Windows on startup use "c:\Windows\System32" as current directory. I just applied Marko Popovic's solution. It was just a simple current directory problem.

**PS** - Marko Popovic's solution is good but @IInspectable warns about incoming bugs that could occured with this method. He recommands **to only use fully qualified pathname without changing dir**.

Comment: The question presumably is something like "how to diagnose the failure mode?"

Comment: Is it possible that its to do with the directory its being started from, maybe loading in a DLL from its current directory and that dir is not in the path?

Could it be reading environment variables that aren't set yet?

Comment: @Matt: That tends to cause noisier failures. But it's not totally impossible.

Comment: You say you start if from a batch file. Does it start if you open a cmd.exe console, cd to c:\ (`cd /d c:\ `) and launch the batch file with its full path from there? Same question if you go in a system directory (`cd /d c:\Windows`)?

Comment: I ran from a batch file for a test. It doesn't work neither with bat nor directly.

Comment: My application need a DLL I put in the same directory. If I remove it, I got an error on startup. That means it runs and terminates immediatly. But I can't tell why. @SergeBallesta Yes it runs from console directly. It run even if I call the exe directly by double-clicking in the explorer.

Comment: You'll surely need to improve the error checking in your program.  A very standard failure mode is opening a file without using the full path name (foo.ext instead of c:\bar\baz\foo.ext).  Won't work when the default working directory is not where you hope it is.

Comment: use shortpath name of your application

Comment: Imagine if your program would have displayed an error message "could not find mydll.dll" when it can't find that dll...

Comment: SQLite doesn't need any Windows facilities to open a database. It needs the database file and the SQLite binary (which is very likely already loaded when your code runs). Marko Popovic's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33810907/1889329) solves neither the problem of loading DLLs, nor the problem that caused your application to fail to run. It does so by coincidence only. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808203/win32-application-doesnt-run-on-startup/33810907#comment55464020_33810907) below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the application is started using the "Run" key, its working directory is not the one where its image file (*.exe) resides. You can change this by calling Win32 function `SetCurrentDirectory` at the very beginning of your main function. Here is a skeleton of a solution:

```
// Use GetModuleFileName to retrieve path of the executable file
TCHAR pszPathToSelf[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwPathLength = GetModuleFileName(NULL, pszPathToSelf, MAX_PATH);
if(dwPathLength > 0)
{
    // Code that extracts directory path from pszPathToSelf and places it into variable pszNewWorkingDirectory of type TCHAR
    ...

    BOOL bSuccess = SetCurrentDirectory(pszNewWorkingDirectory);
    if(0 == bSuccess)
    {
    // SetCurrentDirectory failed for some reason, handle how you see fit
    ....
    }
}
```

This way, your function will change its working directory and load the necessary DLL.

EDIT:
As user IInspectable pointed out, the above approach will not work in the default case, but only in some special ones. A better approach would be to register your application under `App Paths` registry key. If your application is named `my_app.exe`, create the following registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\my_app.exe`
and then create a `REG_SZ` value named`Path`, which will contain the path to directory that holds `my_app.exe`.

For more details, refer to the following MSDN page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Sorry for the initial mistake!

Comment: This won't help, unless the application uses the [/DELAYLOAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) linker option. By default, all DLL imports are resolved before any of your code runs. And setting the working directory is wrong anyway. [SetDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx)/[AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) are the appropriate APIs, that don't just work by coincidence.

Comment: @IInspectable Hmm, you are right! I forgot that the imports are resolved before. This would only work for delay loaded DLLs, or if they are loaded dynamically using `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoPopovic, that resolved my problem. It was not the DLL but the SQLite file. My program can't find nor create this file inside Windows' directory. However I discover that my program looks for DLL within its own directory. I guess it is because of the way dynamic links work.

Comment: @Spiralwise: [SetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530.aspx) is not a solution to your problem. The CWD is a per process property. Any thread and any library can change the CWD at any time (the Common File Dialog does it, for example). The solution to your problem is to use fully qualified path names. And yes, the directory from which an application is loaded is at the top of the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx), so this answer is both wrong and doesn't do anything helpful.

Comment: As my DLL is in the same directory than the executable, it's not a problem for this part. And I get fully qualify path names thanks to @MarkoPopovic 's method, so I didn't understand well what's wrong actually. (However, I will correct my post updates.)

Comment: @Spiralwise: Fully qualified path names is not something you get. It's something you actively use. If `SetCurrentDirectory` appears to solve your issue, you aren't using a fully qualified path name for your SQLite datafile. To construct a fully qualified path name, call [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx), strip off the executable's file name, and add the SQLite datafile file name. Relying on the CWD is always a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Ok I get the idea, I shouldn't change dir at all and rely solely on fully qualified path names. Thanks!