# Program not running from 'Run' registry key

Tags: windows, registry

I have written a program in C# which I would like to open automatically at startup. As such, I have added a value to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` key:

Name: `CustomTaskbar`

Data: `"C:\Users\test\Documents\CustomTaskbar\CustomTaskbar.exe"`

Unfortunately, when I login, I am encountered with an error. Windows says 'CustomTaskbar has stopped working' and the details say this:

```
Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\WERECE7.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
  C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\WERF655.tmp.appcompat.txt
  C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\WERF823.tmp.mdmp
```

I have no idea why this is happening, as it works just fine when I run it manually, either via Windows Explorer or cmd.

I have written the program in C#. Do I have to add anything to the code in order to make it compatible with the registry key?

I apologise in advance if this is a stupid question, with a simple answer, but I cannot find any fix online.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3133249/17034

Comment: Oh my goodness... Thank you so much for pointing this out to me! Now that I can see the actual error I feel like an idiot. The program was being run from the system32 directory and so didn't have permission to create the files it was trying to. Thanks again.

Comment: Please use what you've learned to complete the Q+A you started.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win32 application doesn't run on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808203/win32-application-doesnt-run-on-startup)

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions provided by the link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3133249/17034) kindly provided by Hans Passant, I was able to catch the exception. It turns out that while I had thought it was an issue with the way Windows was running it, it was in fact a stupid error on my behalf. I was referencing local paths like `”appfolder”` and `”config.xml”`. Windows was running the program from the system32 directory and, as the program did not have admin privileges, it was throwing an error, saying it couldn’t write to them.

I feel utterly ridiculous for having not noticed what would be happening before.